# iOS Push notifications not working in production

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So I have added push notifications to my app, everything was working fine in development when i was trying it out, then I switched over to production and was ready to upload to app store, suddenly push notifications were not being sent anymore. I have no idea what to do, any help?

Also, when I run the app, the device is successfully registering for push notifications, but no notifications are being sent or received.

Comment: i face the same issue so it might be solve yours,
Just start gain whole process for push notification and check.

Comment: Did you change the URL in your webservice from the sandbox to the production one?

Comment: @AshishThakkar hi thanks, I guess I will start it over and maybe it will work.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff hi yes I did, it says production there too

Comment: Probably your question has already been asked and answered.please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717275/apns-push-notifications-not-working-on-production)

Comment: thanks but 4 years ago is a bit old, not good information

Comment: for production, notification token is changed

Comment: You access the production environment at gateway.push.apple.com, outbound TCP port 2195.

Comment: right, that makes sense. but where do i put this information?

Comment: add  in the server side code

Comment: please see this answer for detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717275/apns-push-notifications-not-working-on-production

Comment: in server side, there are some code like this

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx); //production

Comment: where should add this push url and port

Comment: ooh, but the service im using does that change automatically  and it states production, so that's not the issue. maybe something with the device tokens being different for each device?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your app is ready to receive notifications from your production url and it's not still set to the sandbox one.

> Development: Use the development environment for initial development
>   and testing of the provider app. It provides the same set of services
>   as the production environment, although with a smaller number of
>   server units. The development environment also acts as a virtual
>   device, enabling simulated end-to-end testing. You access the
>   development environment at gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, outbound
>   TCP port 2195.
>
> Production: Use the production environment when building the
>   production version of the provider app. Apps using the production
>   environment must meet Apple’s reliability requirements. You access the
>   production environment at gateway.push.apple.com, outbound TCP port
>   2195.

Also make sure your app is using your Production APNS certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my app is using the Production APNS certificate. but what do you mean by checking if it's ready to receive from my production url? how do i check that

Comment: The urls mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html