# App push notification production failed (again)

Tags: ssl, notifications, push, pem

My problem is similar with this topic [APNS Push Notifications Not Working on Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717275/apns-push-notifications-not-working-on-production) after appStore release the notifications did not works.

Unlike him, to generate my pem file i used https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/pem and I have exported the app' for "iOS Store Deployment" because i don't have permission to push myself...

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me... In my php file I sent notifications to the "url apple developement"...